# Reading a string with special character in R

Tags: r, file-io, escaping

I have a little problem in reading a file in R. In particular, I run a script that load a file, say X, which stores a string per each line. There are string with special characters like, `'` and therefore I get some errors.

I run the script by command line as follows

```
Rscript.exe MyScript.R "C:\X.txt"
```

The content of file `X` is, for instance:

```
I'll win a prize
I'll shutdown my pc
```

The `MyScript.R` script initially loads the file `X.txt` as follows

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
args <- read.table(args[1], sep="\n")
```

and then uses it as follows:

```
print(nrow(args))
```

The previous line returns 0. However, if I remove the `'` character from the two lines in file `X.txt` then everything works fine (i.e., and the returned length is 2).

Any solution to handle this tricky input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read.table` is meant for reading structured data, ie data that is in the form of multiple fields per row. If you just want to read a bunch of strings, use `readLines`.

```
args <- readLines(args[1])
```

Comment: You are right! That was the problem. For the record: why `read.table` fails with the `'` character and doesn't fail when I give a simple without `'`?